# How to write an XML file by fetching values from Table in Database?

Tags: c#, xml, database

I need to add data to XML file.The data needs to be fetched from the Database Table using C#. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The answer given by Arshad provides you with solutions to create a brand new XML from your DataTable. But I have to ask, do you have an existing XML file to add data to? (Because that is what your question implies) Or do you have any requirements for the document structure of the XML?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu Yes Sir, I am trying to add data to an existing XML file. But as suggested by others below , I can implement the XMLDocument to create a new XML document. Also this is purely for practice purpose since i am fairly new to this concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [DataSet.WriteXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [DataTable.WriteXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
YouDataSet.WriteXml(filepath)
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir for a brief answer. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to enter specific information, [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are your friends (much easier than the old XmlDocument).

An example helper I use is:

```
public string ReplaceInXML(string xml, string nodeToUpdate, string newValue)
{
  // Load xml into a format we can do LINQ to XML on
  XElement root = XElement.Load((new StringReader(xml)), LoadOptions.None);

  // Look for all descendants where the node matches the one we want and update all the values to what we want
  // E.g. Get Node "productDetail" -> and set its value to newValue.
  root.Descendants().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == nodeToUpdate)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => i.ReplaceNodes(newValue));

  return root.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few approaches:

Approach 1

- Read data into a dataset using ADO.Net
- Use dataset.WriteXml() (as suggested by Arshad)

Approach 2

- Read data using SQLDataReader
- Use XMLDocument to create a document
- Use XMLWriter to write to the XML document
- Save the XMLDocument

Approach 3

- Read data using SQLDataReader
- Use XDocument to create a document
- Use XElement/XNode to write to the XML document
- Save the XDocument

Let me know where you're facing issues with the approach.

Comment: My objective is fulfilled by Approach 1. However the Apporach 2 and 3 provide a meaningful approach towards my objective. I ll try implementing them.Thanks Sidharth!

Comment: No problemo! Keep in mind that for bigger XMLs you'd be better off with Approach 2 or 3.